# Testing angular i18n - how to provide the i18nLocale to test

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

Using angular-i18n and trying to unit test with CLI ('ng test') but don't know how to set the i18nLocale for the test's build as I am doing with a designated build configuration for 'ng build'.

Alternatively if I can set this in runtime that would do (note that I can set the locale with ...{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'he'}... but that would not fire the i18n mechanism).

Any idea?

Comment: does your testing console give any error when you set the locale with ...{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'he'} during run time?

Comment: No error but although it sets the locale, it doesn't use the translation from the i18n configuration.